# Nextcloud error - ONLYOFFICE cannot be reached. Please contact admin

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, nextcloud

I have created an ubuntu server 22.04 and from that I’m hosting nextcloud.

I installed Community Document Server(v0.1.13) and ONLYOFFICE(v7.8.0).

Then, when I am trying to open a docx file, it shows me an error of "ONLYOFFICE cannot be reached. Please contact admin"

[image]

In the server setting

ONLYOFFICE Docs address
http://192.168.1.105/index.php/apps/documentserver_community/  I'm using temporary ip-adder

And I want ONLYOFFICE, as it's based on MS Office 360.

Ask anything that I can be of help.

Comment: Use [ONLYOFFICE Desktop Editors](https://download.onlyoffice.com/install/desktop/editors/linux/onlyoffice-desktopeditors_amd64.deb) instead.

Comment: Anything else that I can use directly on my Ubuntu server Nextcloud? As I want to integrate it directly in my nextcloud server.

Comment: Contact ONLYOFFICE support. Chances are slim that someone might provide a useful answer